# Erro no Sql Server: is not a recognized function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tenho duas funções no sql server que não estão sendo reconhecidas pelo banco

```
-- Não loga conexões de usuários de sistema
IF (ORIGINAL_LOGIN() IN ('sa', 'AUTORIDADE NT\SISTEMA', 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM') OR ORIGINAL_LOGIN() LIKE '%SQLServerAgent')
    RETURN
```

e

```
-- Não loga conexões de softwares que ficam se conectando constantemente
IF (PROGRAM_NAME() LIKE 'Red Gate%' OR PROGRAM_NAME() LIKE '%IntelliSense%' OR PROGRAM_NAME() = 'Microsoft SQL Server')
    RETURN
```

A mensagem que recebo é :

> 'ORIGINAL_LOGIN' is not a recognized function name.
>   Server: Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Audit_Login, Line 49
>   'EVENTDATA' is not a recognized function name.
>   Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Audit_Login, Line 52

Estou usano SQL Server 2000

Comment: Tentou APP_NAME  no lugar de PROGRAM_NAME? Que versão do SQL Server é?

Comment: Estou usando a versão SQLServer  2000

Comment: Meus pêsames por ter de usar essa versão.

Answer (score 3):

O comando ORIGINAL_LOGIN() é a partir da versão 2008, conforme descrito na documentação do comando. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ORIGINAL_LOGIN_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

Mesma coisa para o comando APP_NAME() e PROGRAM_NAME(). [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx)

Uma saída pode ser o select abaixo.

```
select spid, status, loginame, 
hostname, blocked, db_name(dbid) as databasename, cmd, program_name 
from master..sysprocesses
where db_name(dbid) like '%<database_name>%'
and spid > 50
```